# How to shell script a wrapper for a service

Tags: bash, debian, init.d, debian-based

I have a system service, `foo` that is started and stopped via `/usr/sbin/service restart foo`.  It in turn appears to be controlled by a shell script `/etc/init.d/foo`

How can I create a "pre-start" hook, so that I can run an extra shell script prior to this service starting?  In this case, the pre-start hook is extra config that has to be fetched from a cloud provider metadata catalog, and then jacked into a configuration file necessary for `foo` to start properly.

I have considered modifying `/etc/init.d/foo` directly, which would work.  But which would complicate expected frequent patch-level upgrades which I will catch by `apt-get upgrade`.  I want to avoid a solution that requires re-establishing the hook.

A second option is that I could create a `fooWrapper` service, remove `foo` from all run levels, and then just start/stop `fooWrapper`.  The implementation of that script would just be my secret sauce + invoking `/etc/init.d/foo`.  The trouble with that is again package upgrades, whether `foo` would re-insert itself into the various runlevels, and I would then end up running two conflicting copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup suggests that you use sysv init and not yet systemd. If this is the case, read on. Otherwise ignore this answer.

In general, you will have a link like `S20foo` in `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d`. The 20 and 3 may be different for you. Normally, you would create a script `/etc/init.d.pre_foo` that gets your extra config and link it to `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/S19pre_foo`. This will start `pre_foo` before `foo`.

Comment: That sounds like the right answer, and a very useful approach.  Just to clarify, is what makes this work the fact that S19 < S20 and I have an (implicit) guarantee that the scripts will always execute in that order?

Comment: Also, it looks like if I did `service restart foo` using this approach, it would *not* re-run the pre-hook.  Right?

Comment: Yes both are correct. And also: be aware that this is not systemd.